# this.shadowRoot.getElementById(...).textContent is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, getelementbyid, shadow-dom

Hello i'm trying to create my first custom component

This is my template

```
     <div class="wrap-boxo">
  <div class="boxo">
    <div class="top-boxo">
      <div class="pal focussed"></div>
      <div class="pal"></div>  
    </div>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="left-boxo">

    <div class="icon">
      <div class="ico"></div>
      <div class="shd"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="type-mex">
      <h3 id="dd" class="main-type"></h3>
      <p class="main-det"></p>
    </div>

    <button> <h3 class="col-txt"> </h3> </button>

  </div>
  <div class="right-boxo">
    <p></p>

  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

in the connectedCallback() i do my settings

```
connectedCallback(){

      let tipo_boxo = this.getAttribute("type");
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".boxo").classList.add(type_boxo);
      let image = this.getAttribute("iconimg");
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.ico').style.backgroundImage= "url("+image+")";
      let main_type = this.getAttribute("main-type");
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".main-type").classList.add(main_type);
      this.shadowRoot.getElementById("dd").textContent("Error")
       

        }
```

it worked just fine until i tried to add a textcontent in the h3  the
`this.shadowRoot.getElementById("dd").textContent("Error")` generate an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.shadowRoot.getElementById(...).textContent is not a function
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (home.html:897)
```

what am i doing wrong?

this is my custom element if i do a console log of
this.shadowRoot.getElementById("dd") i get it in the console but as soon as i do textContent or innerHTML i get this error

```
<bo-xo 
  mex="error"
  tipo="success" 
  main-type="errh3"
  iconimg="some-img.jpg">
</bo-xo>
```

Comment: `textContent` is not a function. Change `.textContent("Error")` to `.textContent = "Error"`

Comment: omg i'm an idiot......i have to stop using JQuery ty man!